# size of the textview is not changing as per display type in android

Tags: android, dialog, font-size

I am creating the dialog which displays my custom layout. Below is the code

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutHdr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_small"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/appicon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissionHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/permission_popup_mandate_header"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_dialog_title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The issue here is if the device font is "Huge" or"Small" or "Large" ,it displays the same font , actually it suppose t display as per device settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `dp` for your text size? Using `sp` should make it display per device settings.

Comment: I was using  dp . after changing to sp it started working.